# How to solve Next JS Error: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js13, hot-reload

I have a useEffect Hook that depends on a variable that change every time the url change.

So inside that useEffect i make a asynchronous post request to my express JS Server
After getting the desire data, i use it to change a useState variable that is use to update a component

But every time i change the state of that variable after the request i get this Error:
`Cannot update a component (HotReload) while rendering a different component`

Here is my useEffect :

```js
const [logmFounded, setLogmFounded] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
        nbrLoaded.value++;
        if (nbrLoaded.value === 1) {
            setTimeout(async () => {

                getLogementsByCoords(allFilters).then(data => {
                    setLogmFounded(data.logmFounded);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

    }, [allFilters]);
```

I set the `allFilters` variable in another useEffect

And here is my component that is supposed to be update after getting the useState variable (logmFounded) :

```js
{logmFounded && logmFounded.map((val, index) => {
                // return JSON.stringify(val);
                let { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } = val;
                let { unites } = val;
                let { adresse } = val;
                (Array.isArray(unites) && unites.length > 0) ?
                    unites.map((un, ku) => {
                        let key = `${index}-${ku}`;
                        return (
                            <div className="col-lg-6" key={key}>
                                <div className="card overflow-hidden">
                                    <div className="item-card9-img">
                                        <div className="item-card9-imgs">
                                            <a href="#"></a>
                                            <img src={un.ph} alt="img" className="cover-image" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="item-card9-icons">
                                            <a href="#" className="item-card9-icons1" >
                                                <i className="fa fa-heart-o" onMouseOver={(e) => updateWishlistBtn(e)} onMouseOut={(e) => updateWishlistBtn(e, false)}></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="item-tags">
                                            <div className="tag-option">{val.peutEtre === 1 ? "A Louer" : "A Vendre"} </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="item-card9">
                                            <div className="card-first-under">
                                                <a href="#" onClick={() => { jumpToLocation(mapRef,lat, lng) }} className="text-muted me-4"><i className="fa fa-tag me-1"></i> {Perfuse.DEF_TYPE_LOGM(un.typeLogm)}</a>
                                                <a href="#" className=""><span className="text-muted"><i className="fa fa-user text-muted me-1"></i> Owner</span></a>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div className="dropdown">
                                                        <button className="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle w-100" type="button" id="dropdownMore"
                                                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-auto-close="outside">
                                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                                <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3m5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3m5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3" />
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </button>

                                                        <div className="dropdown-menu px-2 shadow-sm" aria-labelledby="dropdownMore">
                                                            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                                                <i className="fa fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                                                                <div>Enregistrer</div>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={() => Perfuse.copyToClipboard("https://appartfinder.com/" + val.code.toString())}>
                                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-share" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                                    <path d="M13.5 1a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0-3M11 2.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 .603 1.628l-6.718 3.12a2.499 2.499 0 0 1 0 1.504l6.718 3.12a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-.488.876l-6.718-3.12a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0-3.256l6.718-3.12A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 11 2.5m-8.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0-3m11 5.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0-3" />
                                                                </svg>
                                                                <div>Partager</div>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-x-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                                    <path d="M2.146 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L8 7.293l5.146-5.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l5.147 5.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-5.146 5.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8z" />
                                                                </svg>
                                                                <div>Cacher</div>
                                                            </a>


                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="#" onClick={() => { jumpToLocation(lat, lng) }} className="text-dark mt-2"><h4 className="font-weight-bold mt-1">{un.loyerLogm ?? un.prixNuitee} XAF </h4></a>
                                            <ul className="item-card2-list">
                                                {/* <i className="bi bi-house-check"></i> */}
                                                <li className="mb-3"><a href="#" className="icons text-muted d-flex" title='Logement meublee'>
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-house-check text-muted me-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                        <path d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0L11 3.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.293l2.354 2.353a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207l-5 5V13.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-4A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5V8.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708z" />
                                                        <path d="M12.5 16a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7m1.679-4.493-1.335 2.226a.75.75 0 0 1-1.174.144l-.774-.773a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.707l.547.547 1.17-1.951a.5.5 0 1 1 .858.514Z" />
                                                    </svg>{parseInt(un.is_meublee) === 0 ? "Non Meublee" : "Meublee"}
                                                </a></li>
                                                <li className="mb-3">
                                                    <a href="#" className='icons text-muted d-flex' title='2 Cuisines'>
                                                        <svg className='text-muted me-1' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" width="18" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path opacity="1" fill="currentColor" d="M240 144A96 96 0 1 0 48 144a96 96 0 1 0 192 0zm44.4 32C269.9 240.1 212.5 288 144 288C64.5 288 0 223.5 0 144S64.5 0 144 0c68.5 0 125.9 47.9 140.4 112h71.8c8.8-9.8 21.6-16 35.8-16H496c26.5 0 48 21.5 48 48s-21.5 48-48 48H392c-14.2 0-27-6.2-35.8-16H284.4zM144 80a64 64 0 1 1 0 128 64 64 0 1 1 0-128zM400 240c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v8h96c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.7 24-24 24H280c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24h96v-8c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zM288 464V352H512V464c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48H336c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48zM48 320h80 16 32c26.5 0 48 21.5 48 48s-21.5 48-48 48H160c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32H64c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32V336c0-8.8 7.2-16 16-16zm128 64c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16s-7.2-16-16-16H160v32h16zM24 464H200c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24z" /></svg> {un.cuisine}
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="#" className="icons text-muted" title='3 Chambres'><i className="fa fa-bed text-muted me-1"></i> {un.chambre}</a></li>
                                                <li className="mb-3"><a href="#" className="icons text-muted" title='2 Douches'><i className="fa fa-bath text-muted me-1"></i> {un.douche}</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <p className="mb-0">{adresse.quartier} </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-footer">
                                        <div className="item-card9-footer d-flex">
                                            <div className="item-card9-cost">
                                                <a href="#" className="me-4"><span className=""><i className="fa fa-map-marker me-1"></i>{adresse.commune ?? adresse.departement}, {adresse.ville}</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="ms-auto">
                                                <a href="#" className=""><span className="text-muted"><i className="fa fa-calendar-o me-1"></i> Depuis le {val.createAt}</span></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                    : null;
            })}
```

Please guys need your help
The project delay is on February 01th